# File is not converting from json to jsonl correctly

Tags: python, json

Have a project to collect data from Instagram account and collect engagement. The scraper returns the data as a json file. [Here][1] is that file. My function is to locate the number of likes for types of posts and store it in a list. Then sum that list and divide by the number of followers for that account that's bound to a variable. The issue I'm having is converting the json file to a jsonl file in order to iterate over it. Here's my code:

```
honda_follower_count = 4_200_000
def engagement(filename, follower_count):
    """Return the brand post engagement for the Instagram metadata file,
    filename, given follower_count as the number of Instagram followers for
    the brand.

    Returns a decimal engagement rate rounded to 4 decimal places. Python's
    standard `round` function should be used. E.g.:

    >>> engagement('instagram/volvocars.json', volvocars_follower_count)
    0.0125
    """
    engagement = [] #set empty list for like counts
    data = filename #store filename to variable
    with open(data, 'w') as outfile: #save open file as outfile
        for entry in outfile:
            json.dump(entry, outfile)
            outfile.write('\n')
            for line in outfile:
                line_object = json.load(line)
                likes = line_object["edge_media_preview_like"]["count"] #find count
                if num in likes > 1:
                    engagement.append(num) #add count to engagement
                    comments = line_object["edge_media_to_comment"]["count"] #find other count
                if nums in comments > 1: 
                    engagement.append(nums) #add count
                    engage_perc = sum(engagement)/follower_count #sum all counts and divide by the number of followers
        return engage_perc
```

When I test it using:

```
engagement(INSTAGRAM_DIR /'honda.json', honda_follower_count)

Error: <ipython-input-6-7070dc1e8678> in engagement(filename, follower_count)
     13     data = filename #store filename to variable
     14     with open(data, 'w') as outfile: #save open file as outfile
---> 15         for entry in outfile:
     16             json.dump(entry, outfile)
     17             outfile.write('\n')

UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

datadir = Path('drive/My Drive/APRD6342/Data')

#create folder to store instagram file

INSTAGRAM_DIR = datadir / 'instagram'

```
Ideally the function should return a number that's the sum of all the likes divided by the number of followers but I either get a poxipath file error or the not readable error.


The file itself is stored on my google drive in
  [1]: http://ge.tt/2nR5Je73
```

Comment: You are opening the file for writing only (`w`) and reading it (`for` loop over file).

Comment: why would you want to convert it in a first place? Just work with the json file

Comment: @buran I couldn't work with the normal json file because I need to be able to iterate by line to extract the info and that wasn't working with a normal json file. I was able to do it in a previous project with a jsonl file.

Comment: you don't need to iterate line by line - this is json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I was able to figure out how to just take the whole json at once.

```
def engagement(filename, follower_count):
    """Return the brand post engagement for the Instagram metadata file,
    filename, given follower_count as the number of Instagram followers for
    the brand.

    Returns a decimal engagement rate rounded to 4 decimal places. Python's
    standard `round` function should be used. E.g.:

    >>> engagement('instagram/volvocars.json', volvocars_follower_count)
    0.0125
    """
    engagement = [] #set empty list for like counts
    data = filename #store filename to variable
    with open(data) as f: #save open file as outfile
        parse = json.load(f)
        for n in range(0,200):
            likes = parse["GraphImages"][n]["edge_media_preview_like"]["count"] #find count
            if likes > 1:
                    engagement.append(likes) #add count to engagement
            comments = parse["GraphImages"][n]["edge_media_to_comment"]["count"] #find other count
            if comments > 1: 
                    engagement.append(comments) #add count
            engage_perc = (sum(engagement)/len(range(0,200)))/follower_count #sum all counts and divide by the number of followers
        return round(engage_perc,4)
```